# Using loop for creating row in formatted email

Tags: php

i want to create a formatted email. in my email's body, i need to add loop for creating table's row. i don't know how to make it work. my loop looks like this

```
<tbody>
    <?php $total = 0; for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 8px; line-height: 20px;">col 0</td>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
            <td>col 3</td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

it works in normal html page. but when i tried to make an email's body and pass that code to string like this,

```
    $body = "<tbody> <?php $total = 0; for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) { ?> 
    <tr> <td style='padding: 8px; line-height: 20px;'>1</td> 
    <td>asd</td> <td>ert</td> <td>qwe</td> </tr> <?php }?> </tbody>";

send($to, $subject, $body);
```

in my email, it doesn't create any row at all. any advice?

Comment: use <table> tag. in body .

Comment: i did use it. above is just small piece of my code to point out where exactly my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main advice is to learn php syntax.

Sample of proper code is:

```
$body = "<tbody>";
$total = 0; 
for($k=0; $k<3; $k++) {
    $body .= "<tr> <td style='padding: 8px; line-height: 20px;'>1</td>" 
        . "<td>asd</td> <td>ert</td> <td>qwe</td> </tr>";
} 
$body .= "</tbody>";

send($to, $subject, $body)
```

Comment: oh my God ! yes, you're correct. how could i forget about this. thanks for reminding me.